# Among any $2n$ consecutive integers below $n^2+2n$ at least one has no prime divisor less than $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

What is your idea about my conjecture?

> Consider a sequence of $2n$ consecutive natural numbers, all the terms less than $n^2 + 2 n$. Then there exists at least one number in the sequence which is not divisible by any prime less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: Bertrand's only talks about the interval (n,2n)

Answer (score 4):

The conjecture is equivalent to the following:

> Among any $2n$ consecutive integers below $n^2+2n$, there is at least one prime greater than $n$.

Indeed: if your conjecture is true and none of the numbers in the sequence would be prime, then at least one number is the product of at least two primes $>n$, so is at least $(n+1)^2$, contradiction.

In particular it says:

> There is at least one prime among $n^2,\ldots,n^2+2n-1$

which (because $n^2$ and $n^2+2n$ are never prime) is the same as

> There is at least one prime among $n^2+1,\ldots,n^2+2n$

which is **[Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture)** and is unsolved.

Comment: I know Legendre's conjecture.I'm looking for a counterexample to my conjecture